# python plotly - arranging odd number of subplots

Tags: python, plotly, subplot

Toy example:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=3,
                    shared_yaxes=True,
                   horizontal_spacing=0.02)

fig.add_scatter(x=[1,2,3],y=[1,2,3], row=1, col=1)
fig.add_scatter(x=[1,2,3],y=[1,2,3], row=1, col=2)
fig.add_scatter(x=[1,2,3],y=[1,2,3], row=1, col=3)
fig.add_scatter(x=[1,2,3],y=[1,2,3], row=2, col=1)
fig.add_scatter(x=[1,2,3],y=[1,2,3], row=2, col=2)

fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
fig.show()
```

[image]

I would like to push the two subplots in the bottom row to the right, so they are placed in the middle. Something like this:
[image]

Is there a way to do it programatically? I've tried playing with the `specs` option of `make_subplots`, but without success.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but why do you want this? While the second version is prettier, the first one is much easier to read

Comment: This might solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67092558/matplotlib-align-uneven-number-of-subplots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set up your subplot based on the examples in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/#multiple-custom-sized-subplots). To center the graph of the second row in this case, use two columns, each with five rows in the first row. The second row uses two columns for the second and third rows. None, which is not in the graph, must be included in the number of columns.

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=6,
    specs=[
        [{'colspan': 2}, None, {'colspan': 2}, None, {'colspan': 2},None],
        [None, {'colspan': 2}, None, {'colspan': 2}, None, None]
          ],
    shared_yaxes=True,
    horizontal_spacing=0.02,
    print_grid=True)

fig.add_scatter(x=[1,2,3],y=[1,2,3], row=1, col=1)
fig.add_scatter(x=[1,2,3],y=[1,2,3], row=1, col=3)
fig.add_scatter(x=[1,2,3],y=[1,2,3], row=1, col=5)
fig.add_scatter(x=[1,2,3],y=[1,2,3], row=2, col=2)
fig.add_scatter(x=[1,2,3],y=[1,2,3], row=2, col=4)

fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
fig.show()

This is the format of your plot grid:
[ (1,1) x,y             -      ]  [ (1,3) x2,y2           -      ]  [ (1,5) x3,y3           -      ]
    (empty)      [ (2,2) x4,y4           -      ]  [ (2,4) x5,y5           -      ]      (empty)
```

[image]